# Problema al exportar con HTML2Canvas

Tags: javascript

Necesito capturar un div haciendo click a un `<a id="capture">exportar png</a>` y luego guardar automáticamente en una carpeta me podrían ayudar con algún ejemplo seria de mucha ayuda. Gracias.

```js
$(function() {
  function downloadCanvas(canvasId, filename) {
    // Obteniendo la etiqueta la cual se desea convertir en imagen
    var domElement = document.getElementById(canvasId);

    // Utilizando la función html2canvas para hacer la conversión
    html2canvas(domElement, {
      onrendered: function(domElementCanvas) {
        // Obteniendo el contexto del canvas ya generado
        var context = domElementCanvas.getContext('2d');

        // Creando enlace para descargar la imagen generada
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = domElementCanvas.toDataURL("img/png");
        link.download = filename;

        // Chequeando para browsers más viejos
        if (document.createEvent) {
          var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
          // Simulando clic para descargar
          event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            false, false, false, false,
            0, null);
          link.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else {
          // Simulando clic para descargar
          link.click();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // Haciendo la conversión y descarga de la imagen al presionar el botón
  $('#boton-descarga').click(function() {
    downloadCanvas('imagen', 'imagen.png');
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Convertir HTML en imagen </title>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="imagen">
    aqui es lo que quiero convertir o capturar en imagen para descargar automaticamente en la caperta /img.
  </div>
  <a id="boton-descarga" href="#!">Descargar imagen</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola Michael. Has de explicar mejor lo que necesitas hacer y lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Listo amigo ya edite a ver si tiene algún error. Seria de mucha ayuda!

Comment: que no funciona, que error te tira?

Comment: en si no hace nada ni error arroja!

Comment: Estas seguro que las rutas tanto a jquery.min.js y html2canvas.js estan bien? tu codigo tal cual como esta a mi me funciona correctamente.

Comment: si amigo están bien las rutas! de verdad no entiendo por que no me funciona y a ti si :s

Comment: y en la consola no ves ningun error?

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 20,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: ese error te indica que la libreria de jquery no se esta cargando correctamente, debes tener mal la ruta a ese archivo

Comment: ahora me da otros errores en la consola, lo quite local.

Answer (score 0):

OK, La solucion es la sigueinte

Ya que el evento **onrendered** esta obsoleto se usa html2canvas(domElement).then(domElementCanvas => {
//FUNCION AQUI
});

SUSTITUYENDOLO EN TU CÓDIGO QUEDARÍA ASI.

```
$(function() {
        function downloadCanvas(canvasId, filename) {
            // Obteniendo la etiqueta la cual se desea convertir en imagen
            var domElement = document.getElementById(canvasId);


        html2canvas(domElement).then(domElementCanvas => {
            var context = domElementCanvas.getContext('2d');

            // Creando enlace para descargar la imagen generada
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = domElementCanvas.toDataURL("img/png");
            link.download = filename;

            // Chequeando para browsers más viejos
            if (document.createEvent) {
            var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            // Simulando clic para descargar
            event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0,
                false, false, false, false,
                0, null);
            link.dispatchEvent(event);
            } else {
            // Simulando clic para descargar
            link.click();
            }

            // Haciendo la conversión y descarga de la imagen al presionar el botón
        });
    }
            $('#boton-descarga').click(function() {
                downloadCanvas('imagen', 'imagen.png');
            });
    });
```

**Espero y te sirva...**

Comment: muchas gracias amigo excelente! pero necesito guardarlo en un carpeta automáticamente con nombre fecha y hora actual ejemplo(capture_2018_04_23_1500), cuando le de click a la etiqueta `<a id="boton-descarga">Descargar imagen</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos ya logre resolver una parte, agregarle al nombre del archivo a descargar la fecha y hora actual. investigue pero aun así no logro descargar la imagen automáticamente.

```js
$(function() {
            function downloadCanvas(canvasId, filename) {
            // Obteniendo la etiqueta la cual se desea convertir en imagen
            var domElement = document.getElementById(canvasId);


            html2canvas(domElement).then(domElementCanvas => {
                var context = domElementCanvas.getContext('2d');

            // Creando enlace para descargar la imagen generada
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = domElementCanvas.toDataURL("img/png");
            link.download = filename;

            // Chequeando para browsers más viejos
            if (document.createEvent) {
                var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            // Simulando clic para descargar
            event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0,
                false, false, false, false,
                0, null);
            link.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else {
            // Simulando clic para descargar
            link.click();
        }

            // Haciendo la conversión y descarga de la imagen al presionar el botón
        });
        }
        $('#boton-descarga').click(function() {
            var fecha = new Date();
            var year = fecha.getFullYear();
            var mon = fecha.getMonth();
            var day = fecha.getDate();
            var hour = fecha.getHours();
            var minutes = fecha.getMinutes();
            downloadCanvas('imagen', 'imagen_'+year+'_'+(mon+1)+'_'+day+'_'+hour+minutes+'.png');
        });
    });
```